# given two integers write a program that uses function add() to add these numbers and sub() to find the difference

Tags: c

given two integers write a program that uses function add() to add these 
numbers and sub() to find the difference ...beginner to coding..can someone 
tell whats the possible error

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int a,int b); //function declaration
int sub(int a,int b);

int main()
{
  int t,h,x,y;
  x=20;y=10;
  h=add(int x, int y); //function call
  printf("addition of two no is %d",h);
  t= sub(int x, int y);
  printf("sub of two no is %d",t);
  return 0;
}

int add(int a,int b) //function definition
{
  int h=a+b;
  return h;
}

int sub(int a,int b)
{
  int t=a-b;
  return t;
}
```

Compilation results:

```
errors:expected expression before 'int'
 h=add(int x, int y);
       ^
main.c:8:7: error: too few arguments to function 'add'
 h=add(int x, int y);
             ^
main.c:2:5: note: declared here
 int add(int a,int b);
     ^
main.c:10:9: error: expected expression before 'int'
  t= sub(int x, int y);
         ^
main.c:10:5: error: too few arguments to function 'sub'
  t= sub(int x, int y);
     ^
main.c:3:5: note: declared here
 int sub(int a,int b);
     ^
```

Comment: You do not need to specify types when calling function

Comment: That's not the way function calls are done in C. You call using `add(x, y);` instead of `add(int x, int y);`

Comment: In how far is your question title related to the actual problem? Please edit your question to update a title matching the problem.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? This is no place to get your homework done, try googling C language basics and learn by experimenting.

Comment: Debugging is a major part of programming. Get comfortable with your debugger.

Comment: @AlenGenzić C is a very bad language try learning by trial&error. Read about _undfined behaviour_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to pass `parameters` no need specify `parameter type` when calling the `function` in `c`.

Change

```
h=add(int x, int y);
```

to

```
h=add(x,y);
```

have a look at this:-http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2015/05/c-programming-function-calling.html